# how to Deploy VueJS, laravel App on live server

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i want to deploy the App of laravel with inbuilt vuejs 
on my local i just run the "PHP ARTISAN SERVE"
and boom its works for me

but what about the live ?
its not working on live server
my .htaccess and index.php is in public folder

for Laravel we just move the index.php and .htaccess out of public folder and edit some code lines and it will work.

but how it will work with vuejs templates ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment
Regarding vue, you need to create production-ready (check package.json) js file and link them from laravel blade template.

Comment: i am not using blade file, i am using Vuejs Template,
and those template require image absolute path

and for production i run npm run production

Comment: Laravel and VUE are two different apps? Update your question with the directory structure of your project.

Comment: no if you use Laravel then you will get to know laravel has in built Vuejs lib 
you can easily work in vuejs for frontend and laravel for backend

Comment: Moving index.php to out of public folder is most vulnerable act. Please create or change your htaccess in root folder to point the public folder.

Comment: is your app working fine on local? if yes then will guide you how to make it live

Comment: yes its working fine on local but with "php artisan serve" command 
i just  clone my git on live but that is not works even with command and by specifying host and port

Comment: @Jatin What type of webhosting are you using ? VPS(AWS/DO) or CPanel ?

Comment: @Tanja Forsberg its aws

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Please create a zip folder of your project except the vendor folder.
- Deploy the folder on live and extract.
- Change your DB and other configuration in env file.
- In the terminal on live server, run this command : `composer update`
- After the installation, look for your front page.

Hope it should work fine.